# Returning a pointer to the parent activity

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have an android app with a parent activity that creates a new activity:

> Intent intent = new Intent(myclass.this.getApplication(), someclass.class);
>       startActivity(intent);
>       }

The someclass manages a database and I'd like to return a pointer to the database to the parent activity.

Any idea how can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Read this, it should give you a general idea: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what your doing I would take a look at startActivityForResult().  You can start your activity and return what you need to the parent class.

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html

Comment: The putExtra method in the child activity won't let me add a reference to the db...

Comment: The docs aren't clear but I believe you need to call getIntent().putExtra in your child activity and then the Intent argument in onActiityResult will contain the data.

Comment: should resemble something like this:         Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("dbInfo",db.reference);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);        
        finish();   Then back in parent class in your OnActivityResult class you can get the extras with data.getStringExtra("dbInfo")

Answer (score 0):

In Android it is not possible to pass a handle to DB object from one Activity to another along with Intent. Instead you need to find out another architectural approach. For instance, your parent activity should be able to open the DB when it is time to (and probably some conditions allows it). If your child Activity somehow decides whether the parent Activity is allowed to open the DB you can use `parent.startActivityForResult()` and then pass back some approprite result code using `child.setResult()` so the parent is notified at `parent.onActivityResult()`.

[Starting Activities and Getting Results](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)